# Best practice: Task list item security, so only Assignee & Administrator can change tasks

Tags: task-list, security

I'm reading up on Sharepoint and it's security limitations in terms of unique permissions on items within lists (max 2000 per level).

I will have a list/doclib with about ~800 entries, probably with unique permissions set - no problem here.

But I also want to create a "to-do" task-based list per entry. That means I might have 5 tasks per entry in a separate task list - 4000 items with unique permissions might become a performance problem.

Basically I want the tasks to be editable by the assignee (the one who the task was assigned to) as well as certain groups (Administrators). Others should not be able to edit/view the task. I'm wondering what you would propose as the best way to handle this.

It would be no problem setting permissions for the task list itself, so only certain groups can view/edit; the problem is that someone totally different (in a non-admin group) also needs to work on his/her tasks (but not on any others) - the only way I see is using unique permissions per task or to group tasks into user- or group-based folders / lists.

Any other way I am missing?

Can Sharepoint 2010s new method SPRoleAssignmentCollection.AddToCurrentScopeOnly help me?

Cheers,
moon

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://blogs.devhorizon.com/reza/?p=9#tb

In summary, it is a comprehensive solution for applying item-level permissions for CreateTask and CreateTaskWithContentType activities.

You could use a Workflow but I think the solution outlined above is better.

Gus

Comment: Thanks! I know about tasks and special permissions, the question is rather about the limitations of Sharepoint and security principals per list.

Comment: Have you read this?

Best practices for using fine-grained permissions (SharePoint Products and Technologies)

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8176a682-45e9-4d28-b161-5aac4056ed53&displaylang=en

Comment: Yeap I did, was just release by MS wasn't it? That's actually what got me thinking.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

I'll be working on a project in the next few weeks that will most likely use a content type workflow to move items between lists and avoid the item level permission issue. 

Around 10,000 items for 1,000 users. 

If you have MySites could you use feature stapling to customise that and put custom tasks in there?

Comment: Using folders within those to circumvent the limits. It sucks for navigation, as a user has to navigate through all folders to get to the folder he wants to get to but, keeping everything in one list makes it easier again for reporting (also a view showing all files without folders helps)